# Carrierwave filename keeps changing on update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, update-attributes

I have model Company and company has mounted carrierwave uploader Logo.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
```

Images upload works, but I have an issue with update_attributes. When user wants to update only description or title of the company, but not to upload new image - filename value in DB is still being changed every time. Here is a simple example:

```
1.9.3-p545 :004 > a = Company.last
1.9.3-p545 :005 > a.update_attributes(:title => "test title 2")
 (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Company Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `companies` WHERE (`companies`.`title` = BINARY 'test title 2' AND `companies`.`id` != 37) LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 37 LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE `companies` SET `title` = 'test title 2', `logo` = '1396206630_1f288be4.jpg', `updated_at` = '2014-03-30 19:10:30' WHERE `companies`.`id` = 37
   (8.1ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Why logo is being updated here with new value even the new value was not given? How to avoid this?

Comment: `filename value in DB is still being changed every time` with a new filename or existing file name? What is the original file name before updating? Do you mean that `1396206630_1f288be4.jpg` is a new file name?

Comment: With new file name. Although no new file was uploaded.

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same and figured it out that an uploader class' `filename` method should not set a new filename unless `original_filename` presents. CarrierWave has [a relevant wiki page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files) about filename which doesn't directly address this issue, but is enough to get a clue.

For example,

This code changes the filename field every time the model is updated.

```
class SampleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def filename
    "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.jpg"
  end
end
```

However this extra if statement prevents the former behaviour.

```
class SampleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def filename
    "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.jpg" if original_filename.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked for me. Nonetheless it's weird that carrierwave fires this filename method every time the record gets updated.