# carrierwave deletes user avatar on user profile update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

User creates profile and upload avatar.... that's OK. But then user decide to add some more info so will visit profile settings second time and change only one or two text fields but no avatar. 
But after saving changes avatar disappears. I want it to stay there if it was not changed.

validations, parameters disallow if avatar not selected, nothing seems to help.

EDIT: adding some code

blog.rb model:

```
mount_uploader :blog_title_img, BlogTitleUploader
```

blog_title_uploader.rb:

```
 class BlogTitleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  storage :file

  kvalita = 90

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  version :thumb464 do
      process :resize_to_fill => [464,304]
      process :convert => 'jpg'
      process :quality => kvalita
  end

  version :thumb340, from_version: :thumb464  do
      process :resize_to_fill => [340,304]
      process :convert => 'jpg'
      process :quality => kvalita
  end

  version :thumb320, from_version: :thumb464 do
      process :resize_to_fill => [320,200]
      process :convert => 'jpg'
      process :quality => kvalita
  end

  version :thumb288, from_version: :thumb464 do
      process :resize_to_fill => [288,304]
      process :convert => 'jpg'
      process :quality => kvalita
  end

  version :thumb256, from_version: :thumb464 do
      process :resize_to_fill => [256,304]
      process :convert => 'jpg'
      process :quality => kvalita
  end

  version :thumb224, from_version: :thumb464 do
      process :resize_to_fill => [224,304]
      process :convert => 'jpg'
      process :quality => kvalita
  end

  def filename
    "#{secure_token()}.jpg"
  end

  def secure_token(length=16)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end


end
```

blogs/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= 

render partial: "shared/editor",
object: @blog,
locals: { 
    backlink: @backlink, 
    title_image: :blog_title_img
}

%>
```

shared/_editor.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for editor do |f| %>
    <b>Nadpis</b>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class:"nadpis" %>
    <br>
    <b>Link</b>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_field :link, class:"nadpis" %>
    <% if defined?(editor.tags) %>
        <br>
        <b>Tagy</b>
        <br>
        <%= f.text_field :tags, class:"nadpis" %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <b>Úvodný text / popis</b>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class:"nadpis" %>
    <br>
    <b>Text</b>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_area :text, class:"text" %>
    <br>
    <b>Titulný obrázok</b>
    <br>
    <%= image_tag(editor.send(title_image).thumb320.url) if editor.send(title_image) != nil %>
    <br>
    <%= f.file_field title_image %>
    <br>
    <%= f.hidden_field title_image.to_s + "_cache" %>
    <br>
    <% if defined?(kategorie) #&& z.length > 0
        z = kategorie.reflections[kategorie.reflections.keys.first].active_record.all
        z.each do |ch| %>
            <span>
                <%= check_box "pica", :id, { multiple: true, checked: in_result_set(kategorie, ch) }, ch.id, nil %>
                <%= ch.title %>
            </span>
        <% end %>
        <br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.radio_button :visible, true %> Publikovať po odoslaní
    <br>
    <%= f.radio_button :visible, false %> Zatiaľ nepublikovať
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :typ, value: params[:typ] %>
    <%= f.submit "Uložiť" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Some code would help. 
Are you mounting uploaders for active record or using your own configuration?

Answer (score 0):

OK for future visitors with similar problem I finally found solution:

in blog_title_uploader.rb change:

```
def filename
    "#{secure_token()}.jpg" 
end
```

to:

```
def filename
    "#{secure_token()}.jpg" if original_filename.present?
end
```

now page behaves as desired. I should try to look to console output and analyze what is it doing under the hood sooner...

solution taken from here: [Carrierwave filename keeps changing on update_attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748385/carrierwave-filename-keeps-changing-on-update-attributes)